# Get-Content - cannot find path error in windows command prompt

Tags: powershell, cmd

I was trying to execute powershell script from Cmd.

```
C:\powershell C:\Powershell_Scripts\CheckWebSiteExists.ps1

Error : Get-Content : Cannot find path '\\XXXX\China-team\Release
Package\CustomerDB_file\CustomerDB.txt' because it does not
exist.
```

Powershell script :

```
$test = (Get-Content "\\XXXX\China-team\Release Package\\CustomerDB_file\CustomerDB.txt") -split ','
```

this was running fine in powershell but not in cmd. I have mapped that share path and tried executing, but no luck.

Comment: You aren't running powershell. Your conceptual model of how windows works at all levels are wrong.

Comment: please provide me the solution to run that script in cmd successfully.

Comment: The first step: make sure the path to CustomerDB.txt is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

`powershell -command "$test = (Get-Content "\\XXXX\China-team\Release Package\\CustomerDB_file\CustomerDB.txt") -split ','"`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that PowerShell cannot find the filename you have specified. Take a step back and verify that the file is there.

```
Test-Path '\\XXXX\China-team\Release Package\\CustomerDB_file\CustomerDB.txt'
```

If that does not return True, try removing the escaped backslash.

```
Test-Path '\\XXXX\China-team\Release Package\CustomerDB_file\CustomerDB.txt'
```

If Test-Path cannot return True, then the file cannot be found. There is no point in using Get-Content until the file can be found.